# modal Provider does not display modals when function called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using next.js with a src Directory. In the src I have a comonents folder and i am building it as such:

```bash
├── src                  
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── layout
│   │   │   ├── NavBar.tsx
│   │   │   └── ect...
│   │   └── modals
│   │       ├── Modal
│   │       ├── Modal.tsx  # I now I should make this a index file inside of the modal folder haven't got there yet
│   │       └── index.tsx
│   ├── enhancers
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── api
│   │   ├── _document.tsx
│   │   ├── _app.tsx
│   │   └── ect...
│   └── styles
└── ...
```

so the problem i am having is getting the modals to show up I can recognize that the login button from the Navbar.tsx is being clicked, but it does not handle `showModal('login')`

for reference my Modal Provider is as follows:

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useState, ReactNode, useEffect} from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import LoginModal from './Modal/LoginModal'
import RegisterModal from './Modal/RegisterModal'
import { handleDiscord, handleTwitch, handleGoogle } from './utils/auth'

const Modal = dynamic(() => import('./Modal'), { ssr: false });

interface ModalContextProps {
    showModal: (modalName: string) => void
    closeModal: () => void
}

const ModalContext = createContext<ModalContextProps>({
    showModal: () => {
        throw new Error('showModal() not implemented')
    },
    closeModal: () => {
        throw new Error('closeModal() not implemented')
    },
})

const ModalProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
    const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
    const [modal, setModal] = useState<React.ReactNode>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsMounted(true);
    }, []);

    if (!isMounted) {
        return null;
    }

    const showModal = (modalName: string) => {
        console.log('showModal' + modalName)
        switch (modalName) {
            case 'login':
                setModal(
                    <LoginModal
                        show={true}
                        onClose={closeModal}
                        handleGoogle={handleGoogle}
                        handleDiscord={handleDiscord}
                        handleTwitch={handleTwitch}
                    />
                )
                break
            case 'register':
                setModal(
                    <RegisterModal
                        show={true}
                        onClose={closeModal}
                        handleGoogle={handleGoogle}
                        handleDiscord={handleDiscord}
                        handleTwitch={handleTwitch}
                    />
                )
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }

    const closeModal = () => {
        setModal(null)
    }

    const modalRoot = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? document.getElementById('modal-root') : null;

    if (!modalRoot) {
        throw new Error("Can't find #modal-root element.")
    }

    return (
        <ModalContext.Provider value={{ showModal, closeModal }}>
            {children}
            {createPortal(
                <Modal show={Boolean(modal)} onHide={closeModal} />,
                modalRoot
            )}
            <ToastContainer />
        </ModalContext.Provider>
    )
}

const useModal = () => useContext(ModalContext)

export { ModalProvider, useModal, toast }
```

the modal-root is a div inside of the _document.tsx, and the modal provider is in the _app.tsx. I know my Modals Work so I believe it is the provider. but for the sake of information I will provide one of the Modals

LoginModal.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { FaDiscord, FaGoogle, FaTwitch } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { ImCross } from 'react-icons/im'
import Modal from '../Modal'
import styles from '../../../styles/modal.module.scss'

interface LoginModalProps {
    show: boolean
    onClose: () => void
    handleGoogle: () => void
    handleDiscord: () => void
    handleTwitch: () => void
    handleRegister?: () => void
}

const LoginModal: React.FC<LoginModalProps> = ({
    onClose,
    handleGoogle,
    handleDiscord,
    handleTwitch,
    handleRegister,
    show,
}) => {
    console.log("show: ", show)
    return (
        <Modal onClose={onClose} title="Login" isOpen={show}>
            <div className={styles.body}>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            className={styles.input}
                            type="email"
                            placeholder="Enter email"
                        />
                        <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                            We&apos;ll never share your email with anyone else.
                        </Form.Text>
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            className={styles.input}
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <div className={styles.buttonsRow}>
                        <div className={styles.buttons}>
                            <Button
                                className={styles.Button}
                                variant="primary"
                                type="submit"
                            >
                                Login
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.buttons}>
                            <Button
                                className={styles.Button}
                                variant="secondary"
                                onClick={handleRegister}
                            >
                                Register
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Form>

                {/*
                    Login Buttons for Oauth
                */}
                <p className={styles.or}>or</p>
                <div className={styles.buttonsRow}>
                    <div className={styles.buttons}>
                        <Button
                            className={styles.Button}
                            variant="secondary"
                            onClick={handleGoogle}
                        >
                            <FaGoogle /> Google
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.buttons}>
                        <Button
                            className={styles.Button}
                            variant="secondary"
                            onClick={handleDiscord}
                        >
                            <FaDiscord /> Discord
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.buttons}>
                        <Button
                            className={styles.Button}
                            variant="secondary"
                            onClick={handleTwitch}
                        >
                            <FaTwitch /> Twitch
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Button className={styles.close} onClick={onClose}>
                <ImCross />
            </Button>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default LoginModal
```

Modal.tsx

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap'

export interface ModalProps {
    title?: string
    onClose?: () => void
    isOpen?: boolean
    children?: React.ReactNode
    show?: boolean
    onHide?: () => void
}

const CustomModal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({
    title,
    onClose,
    isOpen,
    children,
}) => {
    const modalRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)


    useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
            if (
                modalRef.current instanceof HTMLElement &&
                modalRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)
            ) {
                onClose?.()
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
        }
    }, [modalRef, onClose, isOpen])

    return (
        <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={onClose} ref={modalRef}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{title}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>{children}</Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default CustomModal
```

any and all help would be appreciated, I am sure I messed something up, or i am missing something, again.